Fill the circles to ensure all six triangular sums are equal
Using all the integers {0, 1, 2, ..., 9} each exactly once, place a number into each circle in the diagram below.
For each of the six shaded triangles the sum of the numbers in its three vertices is calculated.
The goal is to ensure all six triangular sums are equal.

Attribution:  Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)

I feel like this has been asked here before, but it's hard to search for ...

Two answers:

    1    
   5 7   
  2 6 0  
 8 3 4 9 


    8    
   4 2   
  7 3 9  
 1 6 5 0 

First:

  Note that, given a solution, replacing each digit with 9-x gives another solution; solutions will come in pairs.


 Second, consider sum of all circles, minus the sum of the circles surrounding the three outermost triangles.  One way to calculate this gives 45-3*(shared sum), which is divisible by 3; another way will just be the digit in the center.  (Digit in center is divisible by 3, so must be 0,3,6, or 9.)  Shared sum is  (15 - center/3).


 Considering the symmetry from the first note, it is enough to consider the cases with 6 or 9 in center.


 Having a 9 in the center will give a shared sum of 15-3 = 12.  There are only two ways to form a triangle with a sum of 12 that use a 9 (039 and 129) and three are needed.  9 is not in center.


 Having a 6 in center will have a shared sum of 15-2 = 13.  The triangles using the center 6 can be 076, 256, 346.  There are only three ways and three are needed; all three must be used.


 By elimination, 1, 8, and 9 are in the outer corners.  The only way to make 13 with a 9 and two of 023457 is 049.  That forces


    .    
   . 7   
  . 6 0  
 . 3 4 9 


 Putting a 1 in lower corner forces a 9 next to it, but a 1 in the top corner works fine.


With a program, I have found

exactly two solutions up to rotational/reflectional symmetry.

Namely, with the circles indexed as follows:
      0
     /+\
    1---2
   /+\ /+\
  3---4---5
 /+\ /+\ /+\
6---7---8---9

we get:

?- time(problem_pu3).

[0,5,9,6,3,2,1,7,4,8] (sum=14)
[1,5,7,2,6,0,8,3,4,9] (sum=13)

% 17,847,954 inferences
true.

This is the Prolog/CLP(FD) code:
% SWI-Prolog 9.0.4 (64 bits, threaded)

:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

problem_pu3 :-
    nl, forall(
        problem_pu3(Vs, S),
        format('~w (sum=~d)~n', [Vs,S])
    ), nl.

problem_pu3(Vs, S) :-
    Vs = [V0,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9],
    Vs ins 0..9,
    all_distinct(Vs),
    S #= V0 + V1 + V2,
    S #= V1 + V3 + V4,
    S #= V2 + V4 + V5,
    S #= V3 + V6 + V7,
    S #= V4 + V7 + V8,
    S #= V5 + V8 + V9,
    V0 #< V6,
    V6 #< V9,
    labeling([ff], Vs).

